# How to use drupal 7 date_popup to get time only?

Tags: drupal, forms, drupal-7

In drupal 7 with the date module installed, when building a form, I want to simply collect (via a form) a time for something to occur.

When using the form api, I define my field as follows

```
     $form['dose']['time'] = array(
        '#type' => 'date_popup',
        '#title' => t('Start Time'),
        '#date_format' => 'h:i A',
  );
```

This shows up just fine on the screen, with the time picker I want.

When processing this in my submit function, I get no value for this form field.  It is blank.

If I change this only to

```
    $form['dose']['time'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => t('End Date'),
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  );
```

Then my submit function sees this form field just fine, however it also displays a date picker, which I cannot have for this field.

If I set the #required=TRUE for the first example, then validation fails, presumably because there is no Y,m,d selected.  If there was a way I could set a BS value for this, I'd be ok with it as I could parse it off later.

On a sidenote, I've also tried form type date_select in much the same fashion, with the exact same blank results.

Is there any way to use the native form api in drupal and be able to actually get a time through a picker?

Comment: For questions about Drupal there is also drupal.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Date module creates a DateObject which requires a date and time; returns the date if valid and NULL otherwise.  So using the Date module functionality may not work the way you want it.

Maybe you can create the field as a regular text field and use jQuery time picker of your choice (such as http://fgelinas.com/code/timepicker/) attached to the text field as your time picker.

Answer (score 1):

```
$form['booking'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Booking'),
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#description' => t('Please select the date of booking'),
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d h:i A',
    '#date_year_range' => '-0:+1',
);
```

Comment: You solution works, but as per the question , '#date_format' should be just 'H:i A'

Answer (score 0):

A workaround would be to retrieve the time-only date fields from the `$form_state['input']` array.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across the same issue. Here's my solution:

```
drupal_add_library('date_popup', 'timeentry');
$func = 'timeEntry';
$settings = array(
  'show24Hours' => TRUE,
  'showSeconds' => FALSE,
  'timeSteps' => array(1, 10, 0), // Hours, Minutes, Seconds.
  'spinnerImage' => '',
  'fromTo' => FALSE,
);
$id = date_popup_js_settings_id('export-time', $func, $settings);
$form['time'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Time'),
  '#id' => $id,
  '#size' => 8,
  '#maxlength' => 10,
  '#field_suffix' => t('o\'clock'),
);
```